# Does an array of bytes with negative values lose information when converted to String?

Tags: java, string, byte

I've got a code like this where in the encoding i convert the letters to bytes and then flip them with unary bitwise complement ~ at the end convert it to String.

After that i want to decrypt it with a similar method. The problem is that for two similar input Strings (but not the same) i get the same encoded String with the same hashcode.

Does the String(bytes) method lose the information because the bytes are negative or can i retrieve it somehow without changing my encryption part?

thanx

```
static String encrypt(String s){
        byte[] bytes=s.getBytes();
        byte[] enc=new byte[bytes.length];

        for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++){

            enc[i]=(byte) ~bytes[i];
        }


        return new String(enc);
    }

 static String decrypt(String s){
 ...
```

Answer (score 7):

You should *never* use `new String(...)` to encode arbitrary binary data. That's not what it's there for.

Additionally, you should only *very* rarely use the default platform encoding, which is what you get when you call `String.getBytes()` and `new String(byte[])` without specifying an encoding.

In general, encryption converts binary data to binary data. The normal process of encrypting a *string* to a string is therefore:

- Convert the string into bytes with a known encoding (e.g. UTF-8)
- Encrypt the binary data
- Convert the encrypted binary data back into a string using base64.

Base64 is used to encode arbitrary binary data as ASCII data in a lossless fashion. Decryption is just a matter of reversing the steps:

- Convert the base64 text back to a byte array
- Decrypt the byte array
- Decode the decrypted byte array as a string using UTF-8

(Note that what you've got currently is not really encryption - it's obfuscation at best.)

Answer (score 4):

Your effectively converting *arbitrary* byte data into a `String`.

That's **not** what that constructor is for.

The `String` constructor that takes a `byte[]` is meant to convert text in the platform default encoding into a `String`. Since what you have is *not* text, the behaviour will be "bad".

If, for example, your platform default encoding is a 8-bit encoding (such as ISO-8859-*), then you'll "only" get random characters.

If your platform default encoding is UTF-8 you'll *probably* get random characters and some replacement characters for malformed byte sequences.

To summarize: don't do that. I can't tell you what to do instead, since it's not obvious what you're trying to achieve.